# Getting scale override call error from R cobalt package

Tags: package, r-package, cobalt

When I run this code I get Error in scale_override_call(call) : could not find function "scale_override_call"

I've checked that cobalt is being called, I've tried restarting R, I've uninstalled and reinstalled the cobalt package, and even sent the code chunk to a friend who's able to run it fine. But I can't get it to run without the error. Any ideas what's wrong here?

```
match_data <- matchit(
  union_member ~ gender + past_union_member + family_income, 
  data = labor_white, 
  method = "nearest", 
  distance = "mahalanobis", 
  estimand = 'ATT',
  ratio = 1,
  replace = TRUE)

summary(match_data)


mah_bal <- bal.tab(
  match_data,
  un = TRUE,
  binary = 'std',
  data = labor_white
)
love.plot(mah_bal)
```

Comment: A [example] might help us to help you. Additionally, using sessionInfo() may help identify any differences that could be causing the error on your computer but not on your friend's.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your R version to 4.3.3. Was getting this error and it fixed it for me. If that doesn't work, I'd uninstall and reinstall the package and then R.